# Crontab fails because shell path not found

Tags: 16.04, cron

I am looking at the failure output of my crontab.

```
* * * * * user /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/src/code/prod.py
```

I get the error /bin/sh: 1: caleb: not found.

This corresponds to

```
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
```

which is part of the email the crontab sent me. I created the crontab using

```
crontab -e
```

All of it looks like a simple setup is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: When you run `crontab -e` it is already using your username so there is no need to add your username to the beginning of the command.  The only place on the system that you add the username is in the `/etc/crontab` file.

Comment: @Terrance that fixed my problem. i got my solution from https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/ And I looked at the format and paid no attention to the "for system jobs"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `crontab -e` that set of Cron tasks runs as the user which `crontab -e` was executed as - that is, your user `user`.

Therefore, you should only provide the cron entry *WITHOUT* the user bits, i.e.:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/src/code/prod.py
```

The `user` definition you were attempting to use should only be used in the system `crontab` in `/etc/crontab` and in entries in cron definitions under `/etc/cron.d/`.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but the "cron user" probably has `/usr/bin` in its $PATH. So, `* * * * * python3 /home/user/src/code/prod.py` will probably work.

Comment: @Seamus when using crontabs it's generally *better* to use full paths just to rule out that problem.

Comment: It's redundant... but I suppose that could be considered "generally better", for some.  I'm only trying to point out that the "cron user" *does* have an environment, and it can be determined if it's not known.

Comment: @Seamus I often have to explain to people why their jobs that run fine from a bash prompt don't work correctly under cron (or Autosys etc.).  I tell them that it's best to use the full path to everything they can, and explicitly set PATH= what they want it to be, rather than rely on "probably".